# Unable to install Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit

when I install Ubuntu with a USB-disk, following message occurred:

```
task swapper/0:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
```

And my computer have an CPU of core-i7-4710MQ and 12 GB memory.

But, if I install Ubuntu on a very old computer, I can success.It is a double core Intel CPU with a 2 GB memory.

The SSD I used on both computer is the same one. After I installed Ubuntu on that old computer with my SSD, I replace the hard disk of my computer with that SSD witch installed Ubuntu 16.04 successful already, it can't run.

My bios is legacy at first. When I change to UEFI mode, I can enter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq51R.png)  .
But, no matter what I choose, my screen becomes to be grey, and a cursor twinlkling. about 2 or 3 minutes later,  following message occurred:

```
task swapper/0:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
```

What I should do? or what information I should provide?
thanks!

Comment: What installation media are you using? If it's a DVD I'd try and burn another possibly at a lower speed. Faulty USB, DVD or corrupt installation files can do this.

Comment: What does a _U disk_ mean? When swapping SSD between an old and new computer, there may be a BIOS/UEFI compatibility problem.

Comment: @hizqueel I appreciate your contributions, your suggestions are generally good. But **please** make your comments more descriptive - "improved formatting" is just not good enough when you improve much more - here the reviewer has to figure out what you really did.

Comment: Udisk means "USB disk" or maybe "live USB", I guess it is sometiing about UEFI and legacy mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu 16.04 using a compact disk as follows:

1. Power on your laptop/pc
2. Insert the CD
3. Restart laptop/pc
4. Press F2 or F12 continuously
5. Select legacy support  priority first
6. Press F10
7. Wait sometime
8. Now select language & press continue
9. Now select connect internet connection if any & press continue
10. Select installation method & press continue
11. Select region & press continue
12. Fill all requirements & press install now
13. Wait for installation
14. Restart laptop/pc & remove CD
15. Open terminal & run sudo apt-get update
16. Now enjoy with ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Thank you for your patience and your answer, I use a USB disk or.I wiil describe more.